# Switching between system, dark, and light mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI in my Next.js web app to switch between system, light, and dark mode. I am having it persist between sessions by saving the theme selected in local storage. I have placed the ability to change the theme of the web app within a dropdown in the settings modal, so changing of the theme occurs through a `useContext`. The issue I'm encountering is that theming is not persistent across all of my components if the theme the user selects is either the "system" theme (if your system them is dark mode), or "dark" theme. In addition, I also receive this error if my theme is not "light" theme on initial load or when switching from "light" theme to one of the others:

`` Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorInherit MuiIconButton-edgeStart MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-134qg7o-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root" Client: "MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorInherit MuiIconButton-edgeStart MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-6pxnsq-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root ``

After some searching, I originally thought it was because I had not been using `CssBaseline` within the `ThemeProvider` tags, however, after adding it, it appears to have only made things worse, and the error persists. I will show the different behavior in screenshots below:

Expected behavior if in "system" or "dark" mode (This is without `CssBaseline` between the `ThemeProvider` tags:
[image]

The actual behavior without `CssBaseline` on load in with "system" or "dark" mode:
[image]

The behavior on load when in "system" or "dark" mode with `CssBaseline`:
[image]

The behavior when switching from "light" mode to "system" or "dark" mode:
[image]

Listed below is my context code and how I'm getting the theme from the system, how I'm storing it in local storage, and how I'm switching it:

```
const ThemeContext = createContext()

const useThemeContext = () => useContext(ThemeContext)

export const ThemeModeProviderComponent = ({ children }) => {
  const systemTheme = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light'

  const [selectedTheme, setSelectedTheme] = useState(() =>
    typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'system'
  )

  const themes = {
    light: createTheme({
      palette: {
        mode: 'light',
        primary: {
          main: '#0065bd'
        },
        secondary: {
          main: '#00b6d3'
        }
      }
    }),
    dark: createTheme({
      palette: {
        mode: 'dark',
        primary: {
          main: '#0065bd'
        },
        secondary: {
          main: '#00b6d3'
        }
      }
    }),
    system: createTheme({
      palette: {
        mode: systemTheme,
        primary: {
          main: '#0065bd'
        },
        secondary: {
          main: '#00b6d3'
        }
      }
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedTheme === 'system') {
      const systemTheme = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'dark' : 'light'
      themes.system.palette.mode = systemTheme
    }
  }, [selectedTheme, themes.system])

  const handleThemeChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target

    setSelectedTheme(value)
    localStorage.setItem('theme', value)
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ selectedTheme, handleThemeChange }}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themes[selectedTheme]}>
          <CssBaseline enableColorScheme/>
          {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const ThemeSelector = () => {
  const { selectedTheme, handleThemeChange } = useThemeContext()

  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return null

  return (
    <FormControl>
      <Select
        value={selectedTheme}
        onChange={handleThemeChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value='system'>System</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='dark'>Dark</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value='light'>Light</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  )
}
```

Another possibility is that, because of the way I'm handling the showing and hiding of the drawer, it could be affecting the style. I basically copied the persistent drawer example from the MUI website [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.15.13/docs/data/material/components/drawers/PersistentDrawerLeft.js), but I don't think it's the case, as, as we've seen in the images, it it working properly to an extent.

Comment: Obviously this is just my opinion, but I have experienced very bad results when giving users the option of using the system theme at all. First of all, you have no control over the system theme and cannot predict what the end result will be. Second, the system theme (most of the time) looks not unlke the light theme. I would remove any code that references the system theme and see if that helps.

Comment: @Jamie_D That's probably what I'll end up doing, this was more so just to challenge myself to see if I could get it to work properly, but I do agree that it's probably not worth the hassle as there's really only two universal themes in dark and light

Comment: I wouldn't waste my time with the sytem theme since I have wasted it it for you ;)

Comment: @Jamie_D I think the issue is I have two custom components that help me with a drawer, which I think is causing them to not inherit the theme properly, so they won't change properly

Comment: You may try to to add  `<CssBaseline />` to those drawer components, but they should inherit from the app.

Comment: @Jamie_D Actually, after following along with some of MUI's "dark theme" information, it looks like it may be because the theme is being checked from localStorage. Because if it's not messing with local storage, it seems to work perfectly fine. I'm trying to store the theme between sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to figure it out. My issue was I was trying to set the theme too quickly from local storage on the initial load/before mounting, which was throwing the error at me and some components were not properly consuming the theme if it was not light mode initially. Below is the corrected code:

```
import { CssBaseline, MenuItem, Select, ThemeProvider, createTheme, useMediaQuery } from "@mui/material";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react"

const ThemeModeContext = createContext()

const useThemeContext = () => useContext(ThemeModeContext)

export const ThemeModeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  //Check system preference for dark mode
  const isDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light')

  //Check local storage for theme preference on initial load
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      setMode(window.localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light')
    }
  }, [])

  //Toggle theme mode function
  const toggleThemeMode = (event) => {
    const newMode = event.target.value
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', newMode)
    setMode(newMode)
  }

  //Create theme based on color mode state
  const theme = useMemo(() => (
    createTheme({
      palette: {
        mode: mode === 'dark' || (mode === 'auto' && isDarkMode) ? 'dark' : 'light'
      }
    })
  ), [mode, isDarkMode])

  //Value for the ThemeModeContext.Provider
  const themeModeValue = useMemo(() => ({ mode, toggleThemeMode }), [mode, toggleThemeMode])

  return (
    <ThemeModeContext.Provider value={themeModeValue}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ThemeModeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const ThemeSelector = () => {
  const { mode, toggleThemeMode } = useThemeContext()

  return (
    <Select
      value={mode}
      onChange={(e) => toggleThemeMode(e)}
      size='small'
    >
      <MenuItem value='dark'>Dark</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value='light'>Light</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  )
}
```